# forge autodesk viewer api , onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:4

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

i want to use the autodesk's viewer in my application so i used the forge ph client sdk,i made the 5 steps that are herehttps://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-usage-forge-sdk-php everything worked good.
but now, i want to view files in the viewer but it doesn't work i have thies error in my browser's concole :onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:4

```
function viewObject(access,urn,divId){
var viewer;
var viewerDivId;
var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            accessToken: access

        };
 function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {

        // A document contains references to 3D and 2D viewables.
        var viewables = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry'}, true);
        if (viewables.length === 0) {
            console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
            return;
        }

        // Choose any of the avialble viewables
        var initialViewable = viewables[0];
        var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
        var modelOptions = {
            sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
        };

        var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('viewerDivId');
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
        viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
    }

    function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
        console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);

}

function onLoadModelSuccess(model) {
    console.log('onLoadModelSuccess()!');
    console.log('Validate model loaded: ' + (viewer.model === model));
    console.log(model);
}

 function onLoadModelError(viewerErrorCode) {
    console.error('onLoadModelError() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
}

var documentId = 'urn:'+urn;
viewerDivId = divId;




Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});


}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1  /jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

    function buttonViewClicked() {
        var access = $('#token').val();
        var urn = $('#urn').val();
        viewObject(access, urn, "MonViewer");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error code 4 refers to situations where the viewer gets `403 Access Denied` when trying to download files from Forge. Make sure that the access token you're providing to the viewer is valid and that it has access to the model you're trying to view.

If you're still having issues, feel free to shoot us an email to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com, and include as many details about your project, for example, how does the access token look like, the URN of your model, your Forge app ID, etc.